# To make malice overly clear (in Hollywood)

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

This is something that has bothered me for a while and probably the answer is something really simple. Nevertheless. In their depiction of evil, mainstream Hollywood films often humanize their villains. They often offer the audience some explanation of why a person turned to his/her evil ways (social circumstances, personal tragedy, loneliness). OK. But usually, at the culmination of the film, all this turns out to be a red herring. The villain says or does something evil that goes beyond what could be redeemable by these structural explanations (kills an innocent Bond-girl or a child, is actually after the money an not after seemingly legitimate revenge). I'm looking for a verb or idiom to describe the way such (usually conservative) Hollywood films over-identify the villain or how they "overly mark" the villain. It is as if the filmmakers want to make sure that we wouldn't succumb to any sympathy with the evil (or accept any social explanation for the evil); to safely bring the moral message home and leave no ambiguity or ambivalence.

Sample sentence would be something like:

Often in mainstream Hollywood films, the villain is ....

P.S. The verb/idiom I am looking for could be used in any of the art forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a phrase for the final action which marks them as irredeemable, you might consider ***[over-the-top](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over-the-top)***:

> going beyond what is expected, usual, normal, or appropriate : excessive or exaggerated
>   <sub>from *[m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over-the-top)*</sub>

You would use it something like this:

> Often at the start of a Hollywood film, the villain seems almost normal and relatable.  But inevitably, before or during the climactic confrontation, the villain will do something so *over-the-top* that it is clear that he must be destroyed.

Comment: This is a good answer. I think I was looking for a phrase similar to "to make overly clear," "to over-identify," "to over-signify," "to over-mark" or "to over-display", but that it would maybe be more concrete

Answer (score 1):

One word which fits in some usages is the noun **caricature**, where some characteristics are exaggerated. From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caricature):

> **[caricature](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caricature)**
>
> 1 : exaggeration by means of often ludicrous distortion of parts or characteristics
>   *drew a caricature of the president*
>
> 2 : a representation especially in literature or art that has the qualities of caricature
>    *His performance in the film was a caricature of a hard-boiled detective.*
>
> 3 : a distortion so gross as to seem like caricature
>    *The kangaroo court was a caricature of justice.*

Answer (score 0):

> **Satanize:**
>
> Portray as satanic or evil. ‘I don't know if the institution of the
> president is intentionally satanized or not’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satanize

Comment: Might *demonized* be used more commonly?

Answer (score 0):

Often in mainstream Hollywood films, the villain is .... **demonised.**

> b. To portray (a person or thing) as wicked and threatening, (now) **esp. in an inaccurate or misrepresentative way**. (Now the usual sense.)

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/49820?rskey=88N5iB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Conservatives are unfairly **demonised** in Cambridge

[Varsity - 27th November 2017](https://www.varsity.co.uk/features/14051)

Answer (score -1):

In this day and age, it might be considered culturally insensitive, but being an old fart, I would say:

> Often in mainstream Hollywood films, the villain is ***black and white***.

The intention of the idiom is to convey that there is no *gray area* to be interpreted.

> 2. Of the utmost clarity; clearly defined or differentiated; without any room for confusion, ambiguity, or discrepancy.
>      *Love isn't always **black and white**, you know. You have to accept that there are many gray areas in relationships.*
>      *Don't debate me about it. The rules are **black and white**, and you broke them.*
>
> <sub>[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/black+and+white)</sub>

The first example in the citation is the usage I am proposing for your sentence.

Comment: That is not idiomatic in English. We usually use "spelled out in black and white" to mean written down clearly and expressly so that there can be no argument. Later, it became a bit more general, referring to anything that was clear. You seem to be using it in a contrastive role. We also have "black or white" as an idiom, and it is contrastive, or implies the lack of a middle ground, but it doesn't work in your sentence either. In either case, there is absolutely no history of racist usage, but that wouldn't deter the odd snowflakes from finding it objectionable..

Comment: @PhilSweet: My TFD citation has two examples. The first: *Love isn't always black and white, you know. You have to accept that there are many gray areas in relationships.* is the way I intended to use the idiom. The second: *Don't debate me about it. The rules are black and white, and you broke them.* is more in the sense you describe, but does not discount the usage in my answer.

Comment: The closest I could find is in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/see-things-in-black-and-white) - to have a simple view of what is right and wrong, or good and bad. It them lists "naive and trusting" as synonyms. This usage applies to the *perception* of something, not to the *presentation* of that thing, or as an attribute of thing. I understand the usage that good and evil are perceived as black and white. But not that the villain *is* black and white.

Comment: @PhilSweet: I see, you do not consider my source to be valid. Try [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/black-and-white).

Comment: Here's another example that actually references the movies. This works fine for me. From the [Huff Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/byron-williams/black-and-white-thinking-_b_30747.html) - "To see the world in black and white is to live within the contours of extremism. This outlook neatly divides the world into right versus wrong, good versus evil, and yes versus no. [...] Black and white thinking makes up a good portion of American cinema. It does not require much analysis to determine who is the “good guy” and who is the “bad guy.”

Comment: In simple story formulas, the the hero is indeed idealized and the villain demonized. But most movies today try to empathize with the villain, to “understand” him in some sociological or sentimental way. Nonetheless, at the end of the movie, the filmmakers usually want to make clear that these structural explanations are inadequate, and to make their point, they have the villain do something that isn’t explained by his/her traumatic circumstances.

Comment: Technically, the expression I am looking for could also be used in the case of a positive hero. For example, when a seemingly bad anti-hero is shown playing with kittens and pups, or having heart-to-heart with a kid; to make it clear for the audience that he is indeed the good guy. It seems to be as if some kind of artistic fail-safe gesture.

Comment: @PhilSweet: The idiom has always connoted to me that the subject is unambiguous, which matches the definition in my citation. So, my sentence would mean the villain is clearly a villain. The idiom would apply equally well to the hero. You seem to believe the idiom can only be used to describe a dualism, but the *love* example does not follow that usage.

Comment: Yes, that describes the situation to a T.